# Updating game score held in SKScene from a SKSpriteNode subclass in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skscene

We have a main Game Scene `SKScene` which holds the HUD logic and score.

We also have a subclass of `SKSpriteNode` for an object. When the object is tapped we handle the touch in the `SKSpriteNode` subclass.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
```

What we would like to do is update the score held within the gamescene when one is tapped. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: You just want to update the SKLabelNode that shows the score?

Comment: Or you also want to detect that a specific SKSpriteNode has been tapped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **I assume that**

1. `GameScene` has a child `SKLabelNode` named `"scoreLabel"`
2. `"scoreLabel"` shows the current score of the game
3. GameScene has a child `SKSpriteNode` named `"mySprite"`
4. When `"mySprite"` receives a tap, the score must be increased by 1
5. GameScene has a private property `var score = 0`

> **This is how you should implement touchesBegan:withEvent**

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    private var score = 0

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        if
            let touch = touches.first as? UITouch,
            let tappedSprite = nodeAtPoint(touch.locationInNode(self)) as? SKSpriteNode,
            let scoreLabel = childNodeWithName("scoreLabel") as? SKLabelNode
            where tappedSprite.name == "mySprite" {
                score += 1
                scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
        }
    }
}
```

> **Explanation**

The first condition pick the first received touch. If there is at least a touch in touches this will succeed. (And in theory this line will never fail.)

The second condition does retrieve the `SKNode` that contains the touched point, then tries to cast this node to `SKSpriteNode`.

The third condition tries to retrieve an `SKLabelNode` with name `"scoreLabel"`.

The where check that the retrieved sprite has name `"mySprite"`.

If these 4 conditions have success then the private property score is increased by 1 and the text of the label is update.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Right you're saying to handle touches in the scene as opposed to the spritenode subclass. Correct?

Comment: Exactly. In GameScene you detect all the touches. Next you check if the touch has been made on your sprite.

Comment: Stupid that I didn't think that to be honest, I immediately wanted to keep the scene clean and handle everything outside of it. Thanks, I have no doubt I'll get it to work that way

Comment: Keeping the GameScene clean is a good target! What a usually do is creating a TouchManager class and forwarding all the touches from GameScene to TouchManager. So much of the logic related to the "touch decoding" is encapsulated inside TouchManager.

Comment: Do I need to pass the node touches through to the scene, tapping outside the node its detected, tapping the node is not?

Comment: The code I provided in my answer discards the touches outside the SKSpriteNode with name "mySprite".

Comment: Yes, I changed to reflect mine and triple checked the name its correct. Would it be because you use nodeAtPoint and my nodes are moving?

Comment: Actually, if I put a println at the top of the touchesBegun method in game scene, then touch a node nothing is logged so they are not passing through

Comment: user interactions was set to true on the node, and needed to be false. Thanks for the help